# Does jsoup.connect().get() return cached Document?

Tags: caching, jsoup, connect

I use `jsoup` and following code to get the HTML content of a website `Document doc = Jsoup.connect(this.getUrl()).get();`.

Does I get a cached version of the website? Is it possible to request a non-cached version? I knew I could set a header request. Something like:

```
header("Cache-control", "no-cache");  
header("Cache-store", "no-store");
```

But I’m not sure if that works. I just knew that these tags are used for the client browser.

It would be awesome if someone could clarify. Greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any headers that you correctly (HTTP spec) specify will be sent to target host via java.net.URLConnection.addRequestProperty(String, String). You should get a cached version of the page if server supports this header, end-to-end. jSoup just supplies the headers as the request it made and when I looked through the source, it does not make any explicit effort to cache off the response content.

Comment: If I understood you correctly jsoup doesn’t cache by default, right? Greetings.